# Moving downloaded apps on LGMS500

Tags: external-sd

I have a LGMS500 and have installed link2sd and advanced sd card manager and am still unable to move all downloaded apps to sd card.
Any other solutions?

Comment: I had a similar problem in that my device would not recognize my external SD. The phone said the card was there and mounted but the camera would not save photos there "please install SD".. After some tinkering, I formated the SD to NTFS on a PC and put it back in my phone. The phone immediately recognized the incompatible format and prompted to format the SD card. Long story short, my device now recognizes the Card and actually stores data THERE.

Answer (score 1):

Not all apps can be moved to the SD card using the native method.

You need to partition the SD card and set both partitions as primary. The one you want to set for apps storage needs to be ext4 formatted and the other FAT32. Remember that partitioning will wipe all data!

Now Link2SD will be able to "Create link" and move the dalvik cache, internal data (pro version), library and application for to SD card.